# interface implementation and LinkedList

Tags: c#, arraylist, interface, linked-list

I have two questions:

**1. interface implementation**

For example, if we use ArrayList, we can see that ArrayList implements many interfaces, one of interfaces is IEnumerable which has a abstract method of

```
IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
```

If we go to definition of ArrayList in VS, we can see there is a method of

```
public virtual IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
```

But why there should be a keyword "virtual"? shouldn't this method implement the method in IEnumerable? So there method should be:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
```

?

**2. LinkedList**

I see some code for LinkList like this:

```
LinkedList<Data> myDataList = new LinkedList<Data>();

LinkedListNode<Data> lln;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //Method 1
{
   myData = new Data(i);
   lln = myDataList.AddLast(myData);       
} 
for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) // Method 2
{
   lln = new LinkedListNode<Data>(new Data(i));
   myDataList.AddLast(lln);
}
```

I can understand method 2 which is first adding data to LinkedListNode than adding LinkedListNode to LinkedList. But it looks like method 1 just adds data into LinkedList directly?Does it mean that if we add data into  LinkedList directly, the LinkedList will create LinkedListNode internally by adding data to LinkedListNode then add LinkedListNode to LinkedList same as method 2 did?

Comment: [`virtual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) so any child classes can `override` it's implementation.

Comment: ask a single question for a single question-answer thread *sigh*, well you ask what is the difference of the first and the second right? it does do the same thing. have you read [LinkedList<T>.AddLast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132177(v=vs.110).aspx), it adds a new node and returns it.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa I know any child classes can override the method, but as ArrayList implements IEnumerable, but it doesn't provide implementation for the method (GetEnumerator()) in IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why there should be a keyword "virtual"?

The `virtual` keyword is there to allow child classes to override its implementation. Nothing special to say about this. Of course you don't want this simple and obvious answer, you want to know why would someone actually override it. Just to give a very simple example, suppose you created your own `GrooveArrayList` which internally keeps two other `IEnumerables` (let's say, a list of fruits and an array of cars). What should happen if you put your `GrooveArrayList` in a foreach statement and started enumerating it? Should it iterate fruits and cars? In what order? Should it skip some of them depending on some condition? If your `IEnumerable` (in this example, `GrooveArrayList`) has some **custom logic to iterate** things, you would override this method and put that logic. I know this example is kinda ridiculous, but it's just to clarify why would someone need to override it. I actually haven't done this myself, so...

---

**EDIT:**

This is the `ArrayList` implementation for `GetEnumerator()`:

```
public virtual IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IEnumerator>() != null);
    return new ArrayListEnumeratorSimple(this);
}
```

[Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,3e3f6715773d6643)

---

> Does it mean that if we add data into LinkedList directly, the
>   LinkedList will create LinkedListNode internally by adding data to
>   LinkedListNode then add LinkedListNode to LinkedList same as method 2
>   did?

Exactly. When you add `Data` directly to the `LinkedList`, it will internally create a `LinkedListNode` for that `Data`, add the node to its nodes, and return that created node, so you could do whatever you wanted to do with it.

Actually, they allow you to do both ways, so you can decide which one to use depending on your specific scenario. How nice is that?

Comment: Hi Alisson. thank you for your answer. For the question one, I understand what you said, but my problem is that, ArrayList doesn't provide implementation for the method in IEnumerable.

Comment: and I just use ArrayList directly without using any subList :ArrayList, so my question is how the GetEnumerator() in IEnumerable be implemented? by which subclass?

Comment: @grooveline I understand your question. If you just press `F12` inside visual studio, you won't see the code at all. See my edited answer, I provided the implementation of that method, and put a link to the source. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: I actually found a method of "public override IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
                return _list.GetEnumerator();
            }"   I think this is the method I am looking for